# iOS locationmanager doesn't ask user permission even with NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription and NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription in Info.plist

Tags: ios, core-location, cllocationmanager

After submitting my App I need to get user location with CoreLocation (#import ) but it NEVER ask me the permission alert.

```
ViewController.h

#import "RootViewController.h"
#import < UIKit/UIKit.h >
#import < CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h >

@interface AroundMeViewController : RootViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property(nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

...

@end

__________

ViewController.m

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

NSLog(@"LOG: %d", [CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]);

self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
// Set a delegate to receive location callbacks
self.locationManager.delegate = self;

// Check for iOS 8. Without this guard the code will crash with "unknown selector" on iOS 7.
if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
    [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}

....
// Start the location manager
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

NSLog(@"LOG: %@", self.locationManager);

.....

}
```

I really tried in so many way to solve this issue (different devices, allow manually from privacy settings) but I don't know where is my mistake.

Comment: Do you get location updates anyway?

Comment: No in this App, but the same code in a empty project works perfectly :/
I think there is something that silent my request.

Comment: In Settings -> Privacy -> Location Services. Is your app listed? What permissions does it have there?

Comment: Yes, my App is listed but without a selection (Never or Always). If I change manually to Always when I run the App this value change again to nothing ('never' neither).

Comment: It could be that you already allowed the app to use locations. It won't ask again the next time...

Comment: Or, if you disallowed location permission, it won't ask again either

Comment: have you added this property in the info.plist? NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription

Comment: Yes of course I added the properties in the Info.plist.
Ok it may be that I already allowed (or disallawed) the app but if I remove it and reinstall it won't ask me.

Comment: I can't see why it wouldn't be.. but is your location manager being deallocated somewhere? If the location manager is null by the time the alert goes to show, it won't.

Comment: the location manager is not null before NSLog(@"LOG: %@", self.locationManager); [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];

Answer (score 0):

According to [NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/core-location-in-ios-8/), permission to use location services must be asked explicitly, and is given asynchronously, so we can't immediately start location updates like we used to. We need to implement the

```
    locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus
```

delegate method and start location updates there. This method is called any time the auth status changes based on user input.

It seems this delegate method is also called when locationManager is set up, as mine was triggering while splash screen was still showing (when I set locationManager delegate, I suspect), and then again when I called triggerLocationServices(). This could be what is in effect "silencing" your request.

I changed my methods to the following:

```
    func triggerLocationServices() {
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            if self.locationManager.respondsToSelector("requestAlwaysAuthorization") {
                // request authorization to use location
            } else {
                // start updating location
            }
        }
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus){
        if status == .AuthorizedAlways || status == .AuthorizedWhenInUse {
            // start updating location
        } 
        else {
            triggerLocationServices()
        }
    }
```

and removed any other calls to triggerLocationServices(). This, along with the correct info.plist keys, resolved it for me.

Apologies for Swift code, hope you can translate into Obj-C.